Cauchy product for integer sums
For a sequence $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ of real numbers we consider the two sided sum: $$\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_i$$
We say that this sum is (absolutely) convergent, if both parts: $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i,\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{-i}$$ are (absolutely) convergent and define:
$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_i := \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i + \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{-i}$$
Now consider two sequences $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}, (b_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ such that
their two sided serieses both are absolutely convergent. I want to prove, that the series defined by the sequence:
$$c_n := \sum_{j = -\infty}^\infty a_j b_{n-j}$$
is also absolutely convergent, and that it holds:
$$\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty c_i = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_i \cdot \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty b_i$$
I cannot find this statement anywhere, and since I did not manage to prove it, I am not sure if it holds. I did manage to prove the part that $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty c_i$ is absolutely convergent, however I have failed at proving the equality.
I would be thankful for help,
Greetings

To elaborate how I proved the absolutely convergent part: I followed the proof for the cauchy product formula, and used to decomposition into "positive" and "negative" part. This however does not work for the equality part.

Have you tried seeing whether you can swap the two series?

I dont see a Problem with that. We would need an index shift, but that does not seem to break anything.

Yes, that was supposed to be a hint. Try manipulating the double sum a little bit and shifting the indices around to see if the correct thing comes out.

I tried but i always end up with something that does not match. Could you please help me more?

Ok, here's another hint. Try to prove $\sum_n\sum_m a_nb_m = (\sum_n a_n)(\sum_m b_m)$ and see which properties you've used.

Are the serieses defined on the Naturals or Integers?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
